# Two levels of a factor in a linear mixed model; one is fixed and another is random. Is that possible?

Tags: r, mixed-model

Can you specify one level of a factor as fixed and the other as random in a linear mixed model (with lmer)?

Some background information first:
A set of speakers who vary in their proficiency levels (or dominance levels) in English and another language are asked to interpret as many words as possible once in English and once in another language within five minutes. The self-reported proficiency score is gradual and higher when participants are more proficient in English, near zero when they are proficient in both English and another language, and negative when they are more proficient in another language.

The hypothesis is that those who have higher positive proficiency scores will do better on the interpreting task in English than in the other language. Participants with negative proficiency scores will perform better in the task in their other language. One simple method to investigate correlations is to find Pearson’s r with two continuous variables; proficiency scores and the proportion of words interpreted in the English task (English/(English+another language).

```
measure_another_lang <- c(74, 120, 41, 79, 56, 45, 43, 56, 72, 53, 54, 64, 47, 90, 75, 54, 57, 37, 51, 63, 39, 44, 68, 32, 51, 58, 34, 48, 50, 67, 36, 50, 44, 80, 29, 53, 41, 46, 56, 50)

proficiency_scores <- c(87.08024, 111.3099, -55.53908, 86.68562, -2.42164, 31.64922, -12.33076, 13.32078, 37.69716, 66.44704, -33.88776, 24.32318, -111.3784, 27.18608, -37.84434, 84.1292, 86.96463, -83.71868, -3.848974, 43.27664, -71.236, 82.99149, 26.83826, 52.12666, -21.94731, 73.82172, -9.716439, 58.2229, -25.71618, -18.66557, -116.2157, -52.30922, 21.82515, 47.30964, 12.90472, 11.13121, -129.6731, 7.642772, -5.015314, -89.4537)

proportion_english <- measure_english/(measure_english+measure_another_lang)

cor(proficiency_scores, proportion_english)
```

However, Pearson’s r does not include the fact that the experiment includes repeated measures; each participant was measured twice. I assume that a linear mixed model would give more conservative results and I’ve included a suggestion in the r code below.

The task factor has two levels, English + any other language, and both levels are considered as fixed. But "any other language" sounds like a random factor to me. The only criterion for the participants is knowing English and any other language. Some participants are native English speakers, while other participants are non-native English speakers or exposed to both English and another language from birth. Language 1 consists of 15 different languages, with 1 to 5 speakers for each language. Is this an appropriate approach or do I need to take into consideration that languages were sampled randomly in one of the levels of the task factor?

```
data_frame_lmm <- data.frame(speaker_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40),
                             proficiency = c(87.08024, 111.3099, -55.53908, 86.68562, -2.42164, 31.64922, -12.33076, 13.32078, 37.69716, 66.44704, -33.88776, 24.32318, -111.3784, 27.18608, -37.84434, 84.1292, 86.96463, -83.71868, -3.848974, 43.27664, -71.236, 82.99149, 26.83826, 52.12666, -21.94731, 73.82172, -9.716439, 58.2229, -25.71618, -18.66557, -116.2157, -52.30922, 21.82515, 47.30964, 12.90472, 11.13121, -129.6731, 7.642772, -5.015314, -89.4537, 87.08024, 111.3099, -55.53908, 86.68562, -2.42164, 31.64922, -12.33076, 13.32078, 37.69716, 66.44704, -33.88776, 24.32318, -111.3784, 27.18608, -37.84434, 84.1292, 86.96463, -83.71868, -3.848974, 43.27664, -71.236, 82.99149, 26.83826, 52.12666, -21.94731, 73.82172, -9.716439, 58.2229, -25.71618, -18.66557, -116.2157, -52.30922, 21.82515, 47.30964, 12.90472, 11.13121, -129.6731, 7.642772, -5.015314, -89.4537),
                             task = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                             measure = c(74, 120, 41, 79, 56, 45, 43, 56, 72, 53, 54, 64, 47, 90, 75, 54, 57, 37, 51, 63, 39, 44, 68, 32, 51, 58, 34, 48, 50, 67, 36, 50, 44, 80, 29, 53, 41, 46, 56, 50, 59, 39, 43, 46, 38, 30, 40, 46, 37, 34, 47, 41, 67, 92, 73, 34, 39, 43, 72, 49, 82, 28, 49, 16, 44, 43, 39, 24, 40, 86, 39, 39, 48, 32, 22, 33, 72, 53, 54, 56))

summary(lmer(measure ~ proficiency + task + proficiency:task + (1|speaker_id), data = data_frame_lmm, REML=T))
```

This question is edited for clarification, adding the hypothesis and a description of other languages (thanks to EdM and Robert Long). I've also made the r code simpler and cleaner to run, including a data frame.

Comment: How was language 1 chosen for or assigned to each individual? For example, might these be non-native English speakers for whom language 1 is the native language? How many different languages are represented in language 1? Are any of those non-English languages used by only 1 person?

Comment: The only criterion is knowing English and any other language. Some participants are native English speakers, while other participants are non-native English speakers or exposed to both English and another language from birth. Language 1 consists of 15 different languages, with 1 to 5 speakers for each language.

Comment: So what is the specific hypothesis you wish to test with this study?

Comment: What is your research question ?

Comment: The hypothesis (or research question) is that those who have higher positive proficiency scores will do better on the interpreting task in English than in the other language. Participants with negative proficiency scores will perform better in the task in their other language. I've added the hypothesis to the question.

Comment: Big improvement in the question, thanks. As a hint for the future, it helps to call out when you're responding to a comment, for example @RobertLong sends a message to him. I happened to come across this on the main page after you edited it. In general all comments on a question or on an answer get directed toward the questioner/answerer but you might have to call out specifically to others, and I think you can only use one per comment.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @EdM!

Comment: I've added the research question in the main question, @RobertLong. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this example (which strips out most of the stuff except the languages and the division into tasks) shows that `lmer` can estimate the difference between language groups (English vs. non-English) even when English is included as a group in the random effect.  In your case there would be interactions between task and proficiency, but that shouldn't change the random effects structure.

This should work fine with variable numbers of speakers, as few as one per language (in a more extreme situation where *most* of the levels of the grouping variable have only one observation and a few have two, this is still theoretically possible but I wouldn't expect it to work well), and with a random effect of speaker as well.

You should think carefully about the maximal model that applies to this design, but not necessarily try to fit it ... for example, `(task|speaker_id)` is theoretically estimable (because each speaker sees each task). In principle, you could use `(task|language/speaker_id)` (because as I understand it, speakers are nested within languages in this case).

Make up a data frame with 10 observations each of 15 languages: language 1 is English, corresponding to task 2

```
dd <- data.frame(lang=factor(rep(1:15,each=10)))
dd$task <- factor(ifelse(as.numeric(dd$lang)>1,1,2))
```

Assign uniform values to each language, with 0 for English (the model will assume these values are normally distributed, not uniform, but it doesn't change much)

```
lval <- (0:14)*0.1
```

Make up a response with an added value of 0.5 for non-English languages

```
set.seed(101)
dd$y <- rnorm(nrow(dd),sd=0.02)+lval[dd$lang]+0.5*(as.numeric(dd$task=="1"))
```

For more complicated designs, I'd suggest using `?simulate.formula` from lme4.

Fit the model:

```
m <- lmer(y~task+(1|lang),data=dd)
lattice::dotplot(ranef(m))  ## view random-effect 'estimates'
```

The estimated effect of 'task' is -1.24, which is nearly equal to the true difference of 0.5 between English (0) and the *average* of the non-English languages (the non-English values range from 0.1 to 1.4, so 1.5/2 + 0.5)

Predicted vs observed values by language:

```
pp <- predict(m,
              newdata=data.frame(lang=levels(dd$lang),
                                 task=c("2",rep("1",14))))    
boxplot(y~lang,data=dd)
points(pp,col=2,pch=1,cex=5)
```

I'd suggest experimenting with some more complex simulated examples that match your experimental questions more closely and reassuring yourself that the model can reliably extract the effects you're interested in ...

[image]

Comment: (+1) for demonstrating once again how useful mixed models can be. Would this work in the present situation, with some non-English languages only represented by a single individual and a desire to treat the individuals as random effects? That information is in a comment on the question.

Comment: see edits .....

Comment: Would this work, @BenBolker? This is a suggestion based on your answer, but I am new to mixed models. 17 corresponds to English: ```data_frame_lmm$language <- c(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 15, 6, 1, 2, 7, 12, 7, 16, 8, 5, 5, 6, 5, 9, 15, 11, 11, 7, 11, 11, 14, 2, 11, 11, 11, 6, 13, 6, 6, 13, 10, 6, 13, 12, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 13)``` followed by ```lmer(measure ~ proficiency + task + proficiency:task + (1|speaker_id) + (1|language), data = data_frame_lmm, REML=T)```

Comment: I don't see why not.  Have you tried it?  You should definitely consider my comments about maximal models (e.g. allow for among-individual variation in task effects, not just in intercept ...)

Comment: Yes, I tried it and the summary() output looks fine. The proportion of the residual in random effects and the AIC/BIC decreased, which I guess is good. I tried to add among-individual variation with (task|speaker_id) and similar input, but I keep getting errors like "Error: number of observations (=80) <= number of random effects (=80) for term (task | speaker_id); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable." I've not understood those errors completely.It seems that my data only can be used with "(1|group)" constructions. @BenBolker